# PHP - Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that would also identify and separate commas, the equal sign and any other special characters that I might need in the input.

Right now what I have is `$content = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $file_content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Which stores the content of the input file into an array where each element is separated by blank spaces.

However for example for `function a (int i) {};` the array would look like this:

```
[0] = function
[1] = a
[2] = (int
[3] = i)
[4] = {};
```

And what I'd like to achieve with the regular expression is this:

```
[0] = function
[1] = a
[2] = (
[3] = int
[4] = i
[5] = )
[6] = {
[7] = }
[8] = ;
```

I've been searching the web for a while now and can't really find what I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is better done using a real parser, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_split` function with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag:

> **PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE**
>
> ```
> If this flag is set, parenthesized expression
> in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.
> ```

```
$input = 'function a (int i) {};';
$content = preg_split('/([\p{P}\p{S}])|\s/', $input,
           -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($content);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => function
    [1] => a
    [2] => (
    [3] => int
    [4] => i
    [5] => )
    [6] => {
    [7] => }
    [8] => ;
)
```

Comment: I think `[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};\':"\\|,.<>\/?]` can be replaced with `[\p{P}\p{S}]`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `split()` function for this, you can use the following pattern in combination with `preg_match_all()`:

```
[a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z\s]
```

It actually looks for multiple characters of `[a-zA-Z]` (1 or more) or a single character which is not `[a-zA-Z]` and not a whitespace character.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?php
  $string = "function a (int i) {};";
  $regex = "/[a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z\s]/";
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

  print_r($matches);
?>
```

This example can be run [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca8fa97fc2da56ed60d174c370b82c230226005a).

Comment: I like this solution! A slight improvement might be to use the shorthand character class `\w` in the pattern as this also includes numbers as part of variable names etc., like `'/\w+|[^\w\s]/'`.